# Обработка ошибок в Monix Observable

Tags: scala

Я пробую написать реактивное приложение с Monix 3.0.0-RC1.

Допустим у меня есть последовательность чисел, в которой второй элемент не правильный. Я могу использовать `Oservable.raiseError(...)` для обработки этого случая:

```
  Observable.fromIterable(Seq(1,2,3))
    .flatMap( i =>
      if (i == 2) Observable.raiseError(new Exception("Wrong i"))
      else Observable.pure(i)
    )
    .doOnNext(i => println(s"Processing $i"))
    .foreachL(i => println(s"Finished $i"))
    .onErrorHandle(_ => Task.unit)
```

Но здесь мне не очень нравится, что бросается исключение.

С другой стороны я могу использовать Скаловский `Either`:

```
Observable.fromIterable(Seq(1,2,3))
  .map( i =>
    if (i == 2) Left("Wrong i")
    else Right(i)
  )
  .doOnNext(either => either.map( i => println(s"Processing $i") ))
  .foreachL(either => either.map( i => println(s"Finished $i") ))
```

Но писать каждый раз `either => either.map(...)` тоже не прикольно.

Есть ли лучший способ обрабатывать ошибки в таких случаях?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, какого результата пытаетесь добиться. В первом примере ошибка в одном значении обрывает все вычисления, во втором - по сути просто пропускает неправильный элемент. Если нужно так - можно `Observable.raiseError(...)` заменить на `Observable.empty` или вообще поменять `flatMap` на `filter`. Ну а `either => ...` можно заменить на  `_.foreach( i => println(s"Processing $i"))` или на `for (i <- _) println(s"Finished $i")`, тем более побочные эффекты в map это неправильно, особенно если нужны __только__ побочные эффекты.

Comment: Идея с заменой на `Observable.empty` выглядит хорошей, спасибо.